# I'm trying to calculate the area of the triangle, but keep getting area = 0

Tags: c++, area

I'm trying to calculate the area of a triangle, but keep getting 0.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int area, base, height;

  area = (1/2)*base*height;

  cout << "Enter the base: ";
  cin >> base;

  cout << "Enter the height: ";
  cin >> height;

  cout << "The area is: " << area << endl;
}
```

Comment: `1/2` uses integer division, and the result is `0`. Anything times 0 is 0. Use `float` instead of `int` and write `base * height / 2`

Comment: @OP, before posting code, remove the line numbers on the left side of the post.  If someone were to try and test your program, they would have to manually remove all of those numbers on the left side.

Comment: Three things wrong. Firstly, `area = (1/2)*base*height` does not create a magical mechanism that changes `area` whenever `base` or `height` change - it accesses *current values* of `base` and `height`, and computes `area` from them. Second, at that point, `base` and `height` are *uninitialised* so accessing their values gives undefined behaviour. Third, there is `(1/2)` - where `1` and `2` both have type `int`, so dividing them produces an `int` with value zero. To fix those things change `(1/2)` to `0.5` or to `(1.0/2.0)` and move the statement below the code that reads `base` and `height`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to calculate the area before you know the base and height.  So the answer is going to be undefined, because base and height haven't been set (depending on how your compiler does things, it may set unknown variables to 0, or it may let them be random values.  Either way it won't work).  Wait until after the user enters the number to do the calculation.

Comment: He's also using integer division.

Comment: that's it i'm moved the area assignment, but got that int problem. Now is fixed! thanks!